# Multiple Model Classes for same firebase element

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rx-java

I'm working with a application that used Firebase as data repository. I'm just refactor whole my app to implement Clean Architecture and RxJava. Doing everything in this way I found a problem managing my model objects.

Here is my problem: I have a Post.class with the same fields and values that I can retrieve from Firebase database reference:

```
 public Post(Author author, String full_url, String full_storage_uri, String thumb_url, String thumb_storage_uri, String text, Object timestamp) {
    this.author = author;
    this.full_url = full_url;
    this.text = text;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.thumb_storage_uri = thumb_storage_uri;
    this.thumb_url = thumb_url;
    this.full_storage_uri = full_storage_uri;
}
```

Everything fine for now. My problem appear when I retrieve the data from my Observer in my repository class:

```
@Override
public Observable<List<Post>> getPosts(final String groupId){
    return Observable.fromAsync(new Action1<AsyncEmitter<List<Post>>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final AsyncEmitter<List<Post>> listAsyncEmitter) {
            final ValueEventListener PostListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    final List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();
                    Log.e("Count ", "" + snapshot.getChildrenCount());
                    //For every child, create a Post object
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Post post = postSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                        Log.e("new post added ", postSnapshot.getKey());
                        //Set the databaseReference to the object, which is needed later
                        post.setRef(postSnapshot.getKey());
                        postList.add(post);
                    }
                    listAsyncEmitter.onNext(postList);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e("The read failed: ", databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            };
            //Remove listener when unsuscribe
            listAsyncEmitter.setCancellation(new AsyncEmitter.Cancellable() {
                @Override
                public void cancel() throws Exception {
                    getPostsRef().child(groupId).removeEventListener(PostListener);
                }
            });
            //Set the listener 
            getPostsRef().child(groupId).addValueEventListener(PostListener);
        }
    }, AsyncEmitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER);
}
```

With this observer I already manage all the listeners and data calls, my only problem is these lines:

```
  //Set the databaseReference to the object, which is needed later
  post.setRef(postSnapshot.getKey());
```

I think that is not a good practice to set the reference as a new field in the Post Model which should equal to my firebase Json Tree. So  my question is: Is a good practice to create 2 different models? One like "dbPost" and "PostEntity". One with the firebase values and the other one with a builder from a dbPost and the new fields that I want to save(dbReference and maybe valueListener)?

Comment: Aren't you just setting the `key`, a `String` as the new field? `postSnapshot.getRef()` is the `Reference`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, but I need to use the reference where I call my Obserser.Subscribe in a totally different class and I recieve a list of Posts, And in that list i need to keep the Ref from each of them

Comment: But why wrap `ValueEventListener` with an `Observable` stream? You have to wait for the Callbacks anyway.

Comment: I wrap it to remove the listener when i unsuscribe of the observable(which i do in my onstop method in my Presenter class)

Comment: You can do the same with a Ref or a Firebase Query with `.removeEventListener(eventListener)`. But we are going off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally what I did was create two different model class. One of them to retrieve and insert my database params from Firebase and another one used by my app to manage the data with the extra values that it need thought the application:

**App model:**

```
public class Post implements Parcelable{
private Author author;
private String full_url;
private String thumb_storage_uri;
private String thumb_url;
private String text;
private Object timestamp;
private String full_storage_uri;
private String ref;
private Achivement post_achivement;
private long post_puntuation;

public Post() {
    // empty default constructor, necessary for Firebase to be able to deserialize blog posts
}
[......]
```

**Firebase Model:**

```
public class NetworkPost {
private Author author;
private String full_url;
private String thumb_storage_uri;
private String thumb_url;
private String text;
private Object timestamp;
private String full_storage_uri;
private Achivement post_achivement;
private long post_puntuation;

public NetworkPost() {
    // empty default constructor, necessary for Firebase to be able to deserialize blog posts
}
```

[...]

Answer (score 0):

[@Exclude](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Exclude) annotation can be used to exclude some fields from updating to firebase, so you can use these excluded field to store your own data, like the post.ref

The example in my app:

```js
class LocationRecord {
    public final Integer id;
    public final String title;
    public final String address;
    public final Double latitude;
    public final Double longitude;

    @Exclude
    public Integer distance;
```